# OpenLayer Translate event not fired

Tags: openlayers

I'm implementing this example https://openlayers.org/feature-frenzy/examples/editing.html but I can't intercept when a feature is dragged.

This is what I added to the code:

```
translateInteraction.on('translateend', function (e) {
    console.log( e );
});
translateInteraction.on('translating', function (e) {
    console.log( e );
});
```

I create a polygon and then I select and drag it but the events are not fired. My goal is to catch the dragged feature.

Comment: That example is using OpenLayers version 3.8.2 which doesn't support those events.  They are only available in the final releases of OpenLayers 3 https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/apidoc/ol.interaction.Translate.html and in OpenLayers 4//5/6. If you replace the ol.js link with a more recent version it will work: https://codepen.io/mike-000/pen/mddOZvK

Comment: Great! Thanks. Can you put it as an answer?

Comment: BTW how can you determine the OL version? Can't see anything inside the JS.

Comment: It will be somewhere in the ol.js in this case in a comment near the top https://openlayers.org/feature-frenzy/examples/ol.js In other cases e.g. https://openlayers.org/en/latest/build/ol.js the string "6.0.1" buried in the code is used to report assertion errors and can be used to get the version number at runtime https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200602/identifying-openlayers-3-version-at-runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That example is using OpenLayers version 3.8.2 which doesn't support those events. They are only available in the final releases of OpenLayers 3 https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/apidoc/ol.interaction.Translate.html and in OpenLayers 4/5/6. If you replace the ol.js link with a more recent version it will work.